# Where to Start with Salesforce?

Tags: learning

I am a senior Siebel CRM developer having more than 8 years of working experience. Now, I am very keen and excited to learn Salesforce and get certified as soon as possible.

Please guide me where to start from scratch ?

Comment: you can start with there trailhead.. nd they have very good documents as well...

Comment: Your question is almost a verbatim copy of a highly voted question with almost 50,000 views. Did you make any attempt at all to do any research before posting?

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Being new was now much aware about the available feature. It seems that I should go with > admin, dev and then business user trainings in sequence in order to best utilise skill set.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to salesforce world. I also cross trained to salesforce after 8 years of siebel experience.

start with [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails)

You can get started with the developer beginner trails. Then in your sandbox you can do mini projects to get yourself some hands on experience.

Once you do the basic trailheads you can also do [superbadges](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/superbadges) like apex specialist to get more advanced hands on experience.

Always remember one thing, the coding language maybe different here (apex) compared to siebel(siebel eScript) but the concepts of object oriented programming are still the same so your prior experience will only accelerate you learning here.

Below screenshot for developer beginner trailhead. goto 'https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails' and add filters developer and beginner as shown below and complete the first trail.

[image]

Comment: @Adrian - I completely get the 2 down votes part since i did not check for duplicates before answering the question. Can i Know why i got a -10(says user removed) on this?. Just understanding so that i dont run into this next time

Answer (score -2):

You can start with Developer Beginner in trailhead. Here's the link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/force_com_dev_beginner